# make my form in Android goes up when keyboard appear

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I'm having a problem with my login form, it consists of username, password, and submit button. But when I touch my username EditText, the keyboard shows and it covers up my password and submit button.

Then I change my manifest to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

The whole form is now goes up, but my layout becomes resized and it doesn't look good. So, can I control how much my layout will go up, when I use adjustPan?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting
**android:layout_weight="1"** for the all the
texts and buttons used..It may work.

Comment: @gozali for your problem I think you can add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in respective actvity in manifestfile...try this too