# EditText slides all up, I want partial slide, how can I do this

Tags: android, android-layout

what I want is simply shown in pictures. first one is normal, second one what happens when keyboard shows up, third one what I want.

[image: problem picture]

for a very similar question u can get hint from here:

[make my form in Android goes up when keyboard appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400686/make-my-form-in-android-goes-up-when-keyboard-appear/5401170#5401170)

Edit: My manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="main.asil"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="10"
         android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

     <application
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <activity
             android:name="TextingActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
         </activity>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

my relevant xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30dp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_log"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_input_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/chat_send" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_file_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_file" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official android development document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft and look for adjustPan, this should help you fix your problem with the layout.

Change your activity in your manifest file to be like this

```
              <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="main.asil"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="10"
     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 <application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
         android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name="TextingActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
     </activity>
 </application>
```

Comment: this is what I was doubt about it is here          <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

Comment: I cannot see the difference, can u help me up?

Comment: Certainly ^_^, you have ....... android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"....... but you should have this    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: already tried that too, still no help. also added relevant xml file.

Comment: it is updated and, as I also commented Keshariya's answer: "not working, I trial all windowSoftInput modes, there is no change between them. am I missing something?"

Comment: you could set the label to, parentTop alaignment, to set it top of the parent view, but I do not see in your xml file where the label would be affected by another related view

Comment: on a second blank project only for this view, just copy-pasted xml, and what I want is just happened for that project. but for mine, something is wrong.

Comment: I have found the reason, it is fullscreen. when it is used in fullscreen, it shifts all up, but when I use nothing as a theme, then it works as I like. but now problem changes a bit, how to put these two together...

Comment: it seams that an issue on full screen: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497

Answer (score 0):

Write below code line into your all activity tag into androidmanifest.xml file, it will solve your problem.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

After changes your activities look Like this:-

```
<activity
    android:name=".Splash_Screen_Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: not working, I trial all windowSoftInput modes, there is no change between them. am I missing something?

Comment: it seams it is an issue of full-screen:  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497